# Is there an option to open an (output) Excel after execution of a script?

Tags: sas

In SAS I am often doing data manipulation and writing the outcome to an Excel using the normal Proc Export.
My next step is always to go to the path of the output and open the output file in Excel.

Is it possible to open the Excel by executing a piece of SAS code inside the current script?

For example:

```
proc export data=test file="c:\test" dbms=xlsx replace;
run;

%sysexec start "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Office\root\Office16\EXCEL.EXE" "c:\test.xlsx"
```

Comment: Are you running SAS on your PC?  Does the PC have Excel installed?  If so then yes.  If not then no.

Answer (score 1):

Following the documentation, you can run DOS or Windows command in few ways:

https://documentation.sas.com/doc/en/pgmsascdc/9.4_3.5/hostwin/n14rxpt7iu6iksn17r895o6kcpgi.htm

i.e.

```
x 'start "" "c:\test.xlsx"';
```

HINT: Leaving first argument empty in `start` command Windows will run default application to open file provided in 2nd argument.

Answer (score 0):

`%sysexc` runs the subsequent source code as a command in the default system command processor.  Windows `start` command followed by a filename will open the file with the systems default opener for the filetype.

Example:

```
proc export data=sashelp.class file='c:\temp\class.xlsx';
run;

options xmin noxsync noxwait;
%sysexec start c:\temp\class.xlsx;
```

[image]

If the filename to be implicitly opened has spaces in it, the filename will need to be double quoted, and that in turn means the `start` command will need the optional *title* parameter.

```
%sysexec start "my excel review" "c:\temp\export of class data.xlsx"
```